# PHP echo return value of function

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
public function checkbrowser() {
$useragent = $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
return $useragent;
}
```

You see it returns the value of `$useragent`. I want to be able to echo what the function returns.

There are no answers on Google or StackOverflow, because everyone says

> why not just echo it inside the function?

I don't want that, I really want to be able to echo what the function returns.

My most important question: **is it possible**?

And if yes, how?

Comment: yes, simple `print checkbrowser();` or `echo checkbrowser();`

Comment: Is `checkbrowser()` a part of a class ? Why it has `public` visibility scope?

Comment: @Girish Doesn't work, just get a blank page.

Comment: @HAL9000 Yes, it's part of a class.

Comment: The real problem is that `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` can be spoofed child's play through, say, AJAX.

Comment: Try `echo Class::checkbrowser();` in this case or create instance of class, then call `echo $instance->checkbrowser();`.

Comment: @vlzvl Correct, it's not for production use though.

Comment: Cheers. Read this [link](http://php.net/classes). It is about basic class usage in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you type `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` without any spaces. You current have a space between the `$_SERVER` and `['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

When you `return` something from a function you can echo it out by running the function with `echo` before it.

e.g.:

```
echo checkbrowser();
```

If you have short codes enabled, you could do

```
<?=checkbrowser();?>
```

Or if you're going to be using it often, you can assign it to a variable:

```
$browser = checkbrowser();
echo $browser;
```

Full code (functional-approach):

```
function checkbrowser() {
  $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
  return $useragent;
}

echo checkbrowser();
```

Full code (oop-approach):

```
class MyClass {
    public static function checkbrowser() {
      $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
      return $useragent;
    }
}

echo MyClass::checkbrowser();

// or

class MyClass {
    public function checkbrowser() {
      $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
      return $useragent;
    }
}

$instance = new MyClass();
echo $instance->checkbrowser();
```

Comment: I removed the space but I still get a blank page, I tried all solutions.

Comment: OP's "function" was a class-method. There was no other reason to specify `public` in code-sample.

Comment: Ooh, I see. Write an answer @HAL9000 and I'll +1 it as you've sussed it in the comments :)

Comment: @BeatAlex there is no need. Issue solved. However, I'll give you +1 for the best description of an issue here.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it is the most advanced.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it both ways

```
public function checkbrowser() {
$useragent = $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
return $useragent;
}

$user=checkbrowser();
echo $user;
```

or the second way

```
public function checkbrowser() {
$useragent = $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
echo $useragent;
}

checkbrowser();
```

which one is convenient to you according to your requirement

Comment: Want to know who the enlightened person is, who down-voted my answer? Also I would like him to give me enlight-ment regarding the reason he down-voted my answer

Comment: U need to rearrange the code as per your structure. You cant simply copy and paste it like that

Answer (score -1):

```
public function checkbrowser() {
$useragent = $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
return $useragent;
}

$user=checkbrowser();
echo $user;
```

Comment: `$_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` may be returning nothing.